# Get variable from JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have following code in `<head>` which has variables (`emp.longitude` and `emp.longitude`) which I need to get:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">          
        $(document).ready(function () {  
            $.ajax({  
                async: false,
                url: 'GetRecords.asmx/GetValues',  
                dataType: "json",  
                method: 'post',  
                success: function (data) {  
                    var employeeTable = $('#tblEmployee tbody');                     
                    employeeTable.empty();  
                    $(data).each(function (index, emp) {                        
                        employeeTable.append('</td><td>'
                            + emp.latitude + '</td><td>' + emp.longitude + '</td><td>');                        
                    });  
                },  
                error: function (err) {  
                    alert(err +" fail");  
                }  
            });  
        });  
    </script>
```

In a `<body>` a have another script where I need to use those variables:

```js
<script>        
    var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([38.8, -94.8], 5);
    // need to use them below (longitude and latitude)
    L.marker([longitude,latitude], { icon: truckIcon }).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("I am here!");

    var popup = L.popup();
    function onMapClick(e) {
      popup
         .setLatLng(e.latlng)
          .setContent("You clicked the map at " + e.latlng.toString())
          .openOn(mymap);
     }

    mymap.on('click', onMapClick);
    </script>
```

I already have a table which outputs those values in a `<body>`

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">  
        <div class="container">  
            <h3 class="text-uppercase text-center">How to retrive data using ajax in asp.net</h3>  
            <table id="tblEmployee" class="table table-bordered">  
                <thead class="bg-primary text-white">  
                    <tr>                            
                        <th>latitude</th>  
                        <th>longitude</th>                         
                    </tr>  
                </thead>  
                <tbody></tbody>  
            </table>  
        </div>  
    </form>
```

Any ideas how can I get those variables from function in a head and use them in another script in a body. Thanks.

Comment: Those snipplets really should just be code blocks since they are not really runnable.

Comment: So how should it work? You need to execute the second block of code after the first one is done. So make it a function and call it with the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to put them somewhere accessible by both code parts.

The higher scope is the global scope. if you just put 2 vars above`$(document).ready(function ()` they will be accessible in the later part of the code.
Yet this is frowned upon. It's never a good practice to pollute the global scope due to possible interference in other js codes that may be run.

The proper way is to find a convenient object that can be accessed by both parts. The most obvious answer is `document` object.

just do

```
document.latitute = emp.latitude;
document.longitude = emp.longitude;
```

or even better

```
document.myProject = { lat: emp.latitude, lon: emp.longitude};
```

in the success part of your code and that vars will be accessable in the later part.
You can also use any DOM's node to store and access the variables.

Answer (score -2):

Assign the values to var and they will be hoisted.

```
var latitude = 0;
var longitude = 0;
```

later in your fetch,

```
latitude = emp.latitude;
longitude = emp.longtitude;
```

If you do not you have to do as the comments say and create a special function to get the values.  You can use hoisting here, and as long as you are not doing this "a lot" you'll be fine, regardless of the polluting the namespace.

Comment: @Luca but OP is using `async: false,` which is a bad idea....so this will work, just not a good idea.

Comment: So if he puts it in the success method, it will fail?

Comment: My suggestion is to trace it and see where it becomes available.